# Mounting USB drives on command line in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, mount

In Ubuntu, I can click a drive in Nautilus to mount that drive and I do not need to use sudo. Is there a command line alternative to this action? I know about the mount command, but is there a direct alternative to the mounting of drives in Nautilus I can use in terminal? Or would I need sudo access for that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays removable drives are handled by [`udisks`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks/).  You can use `udisksctl` utility on command line.

```
$ udisksctl status
MODEL                     REVISION  SERIAL               DEVICE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
HITACHI HTS545032A7E380   GGBZB6C0  TA8B113VHLXE6N       sda     
M4-CT256M4SSD3            000F      00000000123003454CB0 sdb     
UFD 2.0 Silicon-Power8G   1100      1310054700100740     sdc     

$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdc1
Mounted /dev/sdc1 at /media/yaegashi/58228A6D228A5044.

$ udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdc1
Unmounted /dev/sdc1.
```